# Amazon MWS API status _SUBMITTED_ not change

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am currently working on Amazon MWS api for getting inventory list. The problem is every time I send a request the request status does not change to *DONE* until I send an another request. I already follow the flow chart for the MWS Api report request and i did this to my code.

```
$rep_req_arr = invokeGetReportRequestList($service, $request, $x['reportId']);
if ($rep_req_arr['processing_status'] == '_SUBMITTED_') {
   sleep(60);
   $rep_req_arr = invokeGetReportRequestList($service, $request, $x['reportId']);
}
```

but still the status is not yet change to done. what would be the proper way to handle this?

Comment: What output are you getting? Check if the status is _DONE_NO_DATA_ or _CANCELLED_ or _DONE_

Comment: at my first request the status is _SUBMITTED_ as I call the function again with the same request id it is still _SUBMITTED_ unless I send a request with a different request id the previous request change its status to _DONE_ or _DONE_NO_DATA_. so basically it only change its status if a new request with a new request id is made.

Comment: I can help if you can post he code you are using to request the report.